# Unity - game behaves differently after build

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I assign particle systems to given objects and to those particle systems I assign meshes as emitter shape. Everything works fine in the editor but in the build the particle systems just don't receive the meshes: the particles emit from one point, the GameObject's pivot. 
Here's the code:

```
string nameToLookFor = mf.mesh.name.Replace(" Instance", "");
Mesh myAwesomeNewMeshForNoApparentReason = null;
if (!LoadedAdditionalMeshes.ContainsKey(nameToLookFor))
{
    Mesh m = Resources.Load<Mesh>("Meshes/" + nameToLookFor);
    if (m != null)
    {
        //add to dict.
        LoadedAdditionalMeshes.Add(m.name, m);
    }
}
myAwesomeNewMeshForNoApparentReason = LoadedAdditionalMeshes[nameToLookFor];
var sh2 = system.shape;

sh2.mesh = myAwesomeNewMeshForNoApparentReason;
```

`LoadedAdditionalMeshes` is a `Dictionary<string,Mesh>`. It was instantiated and - as told - works in the editor. 
I did hook up my build with a debugger and no error, nothing logged, it just doesn't work.

Edit: of course I tried debugging it, and the meshes actually get loaded and get assigned. It's obvious as the code works fine in the editor. The question is that why is this not working after building it to Android?

Comment: Not sure what your issue is, but your try catch has an empty catch.  I would try to throw an error in your catch and see if anything happens.

Comment: Sorry, pasted the old code. In the case I refer to, the try catch was taken out, I go and edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the `Particle Systems` didn't receive the meshes were that the `gameobjects` were marked as `static`. After removing that, all works like it should. Now, why this doesn't apply to sprites as well, (there static is allowed) it's beyound me. But for meshes, `static` is a no-go in this situation.